# Specifying a pitch for SetDIBitsToDevice

Tags: image, gdi, bitmapimage

I am displaying bitmaps with the function SetDIBitsToDevice. This function knows about the total image size via a LPBITMAPINFO structure that has Width and Height fields. It also knows about the region of interest to be drawn via the arguments XDest, YDest, Width, Height. All these are specified *in pixels*.

So far so good when the image is stored as a canonical one, i.e. with a row pitch (number of bytes between a pixel and the one immediately below) that matches the image width *in bytes*, with padding (if necessary) to reach the next multiple of four bytes.

For technical reasons, I have images with a larger pitch (but still a multiple of four). For instance, width=1000 but pitch=1024. For a grayscale image (1 byte per pixel), I can trick the function by declaring a width of 1024 in LPBITMAPINFO and a width of 1000 when passed to SetDIBitsToDevice.

But for a 3 bytes per pixels image (RGB), I am stuck because 1024 bytes do not correspond to an integer number of pixels, and I see no way to specify that pitch.

Do you see a workaround or something I missed in the documentation ? (I don't think that the field SizeImage can be of any use.)

Comment: 3 bytes per pixel is 24-bit bitmap and the pitch will be zero at width = 1000 (it's calculated using `% 4`). Grayscale bitmap can be 24 or 32 bit bitmap. You shouldn't have to worry about pitch and what not. `BitBlt` should work fine. Give example of your source bitmap data and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: the pitch is imposed (say 1024 bytes). This does not correspond to an integer number of pixels. [By the way, "the pitch will be zero at width = 1000" makes little sense, a pitch is never 0.] It is impossible to provide a sample image as the existing file formats do not care about the original pitch.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about in reference to "pitch" and "padding". Normally you don't have to worry about these details, except when calculating the total size for storage, or if you access individual pixels.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I do have to care as the image is provided externally. I gave the definition of the pitch, which is quite standard.

Comment: Changing the width from 1000 to arbitrary 1024 doesn't have anything to do with pitch and padding. Try using a 32-bit bitmap to completely avoid problems with pitch and padding. Or let Windows API worry about these details.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: sorry, but from the beginning you don't understand the question. I have no control on the input format, I must take it like it is. Of course I can do a copy with conversion and the problem is gone, but I just want to avoid that.